# GCM service not available on Android 2.3

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have written a simple GCM application using Google Cloud Messaging API. It keeps returning SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE on my android 2.3.6 device but works fine on my android 4.2.2 device.

However, if I switch to another application using GMCRegistrar, it works perfectly on both android 2.3 and android 4.2.2.

Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: It seems there is an issue with the new GCM api. Check this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57699

Comment: @SunilMishra thanks for the information. does it mean that I should better use the deprecated APIs?

Comment: Yes for the time being, till the issue gets resolved you can use the deprecated APIs